# Merge two join values in one row

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I already check the suggestion at the time of add question but I am not getting any solution so I ask question here.

I made query with LEFT JOIN but the issue is I m getting the result but the format and rows are different.

Please help me to solve this. I tried half day but not getting any solution for this.

```
SELECT products_features.qid,features_values_int.value_int,a1.value_int FROM  products_features
JOIN filters ON (products_features.feature_id = filters.filter_feature_id_min OR products_features.feature_id = filters.filter_feature_id_max)
left JOIN features_values_int ON features_values_int.feature_value_id = products_features.feature_value_id AND feature_id = 'F02501'
left JOIN features_values_int as a1 ON a1.feature_value_id = products_features.feature_value_id AND feature_id = 'F02502'
WHERE  products_features.feature_id IN ('F02501','F02502')
```

The result I am getting by above query is as below:

[image: data]

I want result as below:

[image]

Create statements are as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `filters` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `filter_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `filter_group_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL, `filter_sequence` int(11) NOT NULL, `filter_name_en` varchar(64) NOT NULL, `filter_name_fi` varchar(64) NOT NULL, `filter_type_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL, `filter_feature_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `filter_feature_id_min` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `filter_feature_id_max` varchar(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `filter_id` (`filter_id`), KEY `filter_group_id` (`filter_group_id`), KEY `filter_type_id` (`filter_type_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

 CREATE TABLE `products_features` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `qid` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `feature_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `value_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL, `feature_value_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `feature_value_id` (`feature_value_id`), KEY `products_features` (`feature_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143862 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `features_values_int` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `feature_value_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL, `value_int` int(32) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `features_values_int` (`feature_value_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27327 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Sample data is as below:

1. filters table:

[image: filter]

2.products_feature table:

[image: products_feature]

3. features_values_int table:

[image: features_values_int]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected Query for you Try Below Query

```
SELECT T1.qid,
       T1.value_int,
       T2.value_int
FROM
(
SELECT products_features.qid,
       features_values_int.value_int
FROM  products_features
JOIN filters 
ON (   products_features.feature_id = filters.filter_feature_id_min 
    OR products_features.feature_id = filters.filter_feature_id_max)
left JOIN features_values_int 
ON features_values_int.feature_value_id = products_features.feature_value_id 
AND feature_id = 'F02501'
WHERE value_int IS NOT NULL
) AS T1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT products_features.qid,
       a1.value_int 
FROM  products_features
JOIN filters 
ON (   products_features.feature_id = filters.filter_feature_id_min 
    OR products_features.feature_id = filters.filter_feature_id_max)
left JOIN features_values_int as a1 
ON a1.feature_value_id = products_features.feature_value_id AND feature_id = 'F02502'
WHERE value_int IS NOT NULL
) AS T2
ON T1.qid=T2.qid
```

**Output**

```
qid             value_int   value_int
TUR813G12KAD4X  10          60
BAL110924      -35          100
BAL149236      -45          85
```

**Live Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/319266/6

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I m not getting exact result by using this query.

Comment: Add sample data and expected output exact answer

Comment: Yes now I have added sample data. Please check

Comment: and your expected output

Comment: Output is the second image in the post.

Comment: Welcome!! :-) @Pragya